# URLs with /public/ work despite the "correct" .htaccess settings

Tags: php, laravel

I know this looks like a duplicate of about 100 questions, but the answers don't work for me.

I have a Laravel app.

I want to remove the `/public` portion of the URL (as we all do) so I have this in the `.htaccess` in my root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On

# route all requests to public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

This works (sort of). The URLs generated by the `route()` and `url()` helpers are without `/public`. So, for example, `/stock/Microsoft`. However, when I manually enter `/public/stock/Microsoft` into the browser, it still works. It doesn't redirect to `/stock/Microsoft`.

How do I make it redirect?

Comment: Would something like `/stock/brombeer/Microsoft` also work? What do your routes look like?

Comment: @brombeer Sorry, it's `/public/stock/Microsoft`, not `/stock/public/Microsoft`. Fixed it in my question. And no, it doesn't work with anything other than `public`. And it's the same issue for all routes so it's not specific to a single route issue.

Comment: There should be not `.htaccess` in the root folder of your project. You need to set the `DocumentRoot` of your server/vhost to the `public` folder. And remove the `.htaccess` from your root, there's already [one](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/public/.htaccess) in the `public` folder

Comment: I've always had my Laravel projects like this (root folder + .htaccess) and it always worked. Maybe it is related to Laravel 8? It's my first project in that version.

Comment: There's an [old page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#configuration) (Laravel 5.8) that mentions "_After installing Laravel, you should configure your web server's document / web root to be the public directory. The index.php in this directory serves as the front controller for all HTTP requests entering your application._" - that's how it should be done

Comment: @brombeer OK but when I do that the URLs with /public return a 404...I understand this is expected, but Google has a bunch of them in the results for some reason so I still need to make the redirect work.

Comment: That would be the topic for a new question then. You'd need to (probably 308-) redirect anything with `public` in the URL to an appropriate new URL and wait until bots picked up the changes.

Comment: @brombeer This question states "how do I redirect /public/{...} to just /{...} so I think the question stands regardless.

Comment: Have you tried to set `APP_URL` and `ASSET_URL` in your config/app.php ?

Answer (score 0):

That rewrite rule is "wrong" ...you're rewriting everything to `/public` instead of stripping it.
Instead remove it and then set the web-root of that virtual host to `/var/www/com.acme/public`.
The point is, that you don't want the have anything but `public` accessible through HTTPS.

Comment: OK but is there an `.htaccess`-based solution? Without changing the `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: One can write rules for everything ...but a standard setup makes a whole lot more sense. Please stop ignoring the fact, that you're dealing with an improper Laravel setup, which may only provoke security implications, unless it's being installed as it's meant to be installed.

Comment: OK, fair enough. But I still need to redirect the /public URLs to normal ones - some users are coming in through /public and I need the redirect to work anyway even after I change the document root.

Comment: Can't just let the /public ones 404 from now on...